# How to get all texts between the + sign and put them inside HashMap in Java

Tags: java, string, hashmap

How to get all texts between the + sign and put them inside an HashMap in Java

As shown in the following example:
product1 + product2 + product3 + product4 + product5

I need to put all the products in an HashMap

Comment: What would the key and value of an entry in the map?

Comment: Simple approach: split the input at the `+` character and put the result into a map. We can't tell more because we lack much information. Also, I'd suggest you try something and do some research on `String` (especially methods like `split()`) and `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming "product1 + product2 + product3 + product4 + product5" is a string.

You could iterate over the string using a CharacterIterator and only grab the characters if they are not a "+" or a " " (space), then when you hit a plus sign or a space then store the built up string in the HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, String> productsHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

static void productsToHashMap(String str) {
    
    CharacterIterator it = new StringCharacterIterator(str);
    String product = "";
    
    while (it.current() != CharacterIterator.DONE) {
        if (it.current() != " " && it.current() != "+") {
            product += it.current();
        }
        else {
            this.productsHashMap.put("KEY_YOU_WANT", product);
            product = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if I got any of the syntax wrong, I haven't done Java in awhile.
Also there are other ways of iterating over a string if you prefer doing it a different way you can see some ways here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-the-characters-of-a-string-in-java/